# What do you call a phrase that conveys popular wisdom 'A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush' etc?

Tags: single-word-requests

Phrases like:

> A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush.

> No use crying over spilt milk.

> Don't put all of your eggs in one basket.

I feel like I'm blanking here.

I googled one, and I get **proverb**.

But I don't feel like I hear that in common use.

Is there another word that describes such a phrase? I feel like **idiom** doesn't actually fit, as an idiom according to Merriam-Webster:

> an expression that cannot be understood from the meanings of its separate words but that has a separate meaning of its own

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17375/3306

Comment: Did you look up *proverb* in a thesaurus? A quick look at usage frequency suggests *saying* is used as much as all others combined. *Saw* also has a very close fit to your connotation. But I don't think it is as common or widespread as it used to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Aphorism

> a terse saying embodying a general truth, or astute observation, as “Power tends to corrupt, and absolute power corrupts absolutely” (Lord Acton)

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aphorism)

Comment: Very true, but I think 'proverb' is more common. I'm sure that there are many people who know 'proverb' but don't know 'aphorism'. Many people would call it a 'saying' as in "arrange these words into a well-known phrase or saying".

Comment: @BoldBen - I wouldn't call Lord Acton's statement a proverb, as it is attributed to one man, but I _would_ call the traditional sayings mentioned by the OP proverbs.

Comment: I thought of *proverb* as well, but the OP seems to have specifically disallowed it. As linked in my comment on the question, *maxim* and *saying* are also in the running.

Comment: Also: adage, saw, folk wisdom, or cliche.

Comment: @Pete agreed - how about an answer with these?

Comment: I think Aphorism is already the best answer.   But you can add them to your answer if you want. if